# Append ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> to another ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I am using `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` to store my cart items. Each time item is added to cart, item details are set to `ArrayList` and then calls `setCart()` method.

I want if items in `ArrayList` already exist then by calling `setCart()` it does not overwrite previous cart items.Instead it appends the `ArrayList` to the end of already existing ArrayList. I used ArrayList.add() method but it works only for `HashMap<String,String>` not working for `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`

```
public class AddtoCart extends Application {
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cart;

  public void setCart(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
    cart = data;
  }

  public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getCart() {
    return cart;
  }

  public int getSize() {
    return cart.size();
  }
}
```

Method called on `addtocart` button which is setting `ArrayList` in `AddtoCart`

```
private OnClickListener Cart = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        cart = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put(TAG_PID, pid);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_CATEGORY, category);
            map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
            map.put(TAG_IMAGE,String.valueOf(resId));
            cart.add(map);

            AddtoCart obj = (AddtoCart) getApplicationContext();
            obj.setCart(cart);

        Intent a = new Intent("com.example.pb.VIEWCART");
        startActivity(a);
    }
};
```

}

Comment: look it up `ArrayList.addAll`

Comment: when you want to update an arraylist you can use .set and give the index you want to update and the new Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your method like this

```
public void setCart(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
    if(cart != null && cart.size() > 0)
        cart.addAll(data);
    else
        cart = data;
}
```

Or if you declare your `ArrayList` like this

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cart = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

You can remove the `if-else` condition and just do `cart.addAll(data);`

Comment: The first case doesn't work unless the variable is initialized - it'd give a NPE.

Answer (score 1):

I have suggestion for you. 
We have to design the CartItem class instead of HashMap to enable the future changes easier. 
If you want to add any new tag related attributes at later stage, we can add these properties to CartItem class. It will help to achieve modular objects in you code.

Example:

```
public class CartItems
{

    int tagPid;
    String tagCategoy;
    int price
    String tagImage;

    // getters and setters methods of above attributes
}
```

```
public class AddtoCart extends Application {
ArrayList<CartItems> cart;

//remaining code
}
```